# Is there a way to forward declare tables to remove cyclic dependency in flatbuffer schema?

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, idl, flatbuffers

I don't understand how to forward_declare tables in flat buffer schema.

//in c1.fbs

```
include "c2.fbs"
table C1
{
    c2 : C2;
}
```

//in c2.fbs

```
include "c1.fbs"
table C2
{
   c1: C1;
}
```

Problems:

1. Above schema compiles fine with flatc (1.8.0), but causes a cyclic dependency in generated cpp headers! Shouldn't flatc complain too?
2. How to forward declare C2 in c1.fbs, and remove the call: include "c2.fbs"

PS:
More specifically, I stumbled this issue trying to mimic following class structure in fbs schema.

```
union Cs {C2, C3};
class C1
{
    Cs x;
}

class C2 : public C1
{
    List <C1> y;
}

class C3 : public C1
{
}
```

Please help.

Comment: `C2`, `C3` are both enum value and class name ?

Comment: I wanted to make a union Cs having C2 and C3 classes forward declared in it.
Let me remove cpp tag from the question.. my doubt circles more around flatbuffer.

Answer (score 0):

There are no forward declaration statements in the FlatBuffers schema language, FlatBuffers supports cycles automatically. What you're seeing must be a bug in the C++ generator specifically (not sure why, as it does pre-declare everything), so please submit an issue on the FlatBuffers github site.

a workaround may be to stick them in a single file for now.

Comment: yeah.. workaround mentioned is good, as there will be no includes in the generated header, and all classes are forward declared in it.

Comment: do we have any true solution for this now?   the workaround of writing a single schema is making the schema huge and difficult to maintain.

regarding forward declaring everything, that doesn't seem to work as currently only structs in a file are forward declared in it, and structs of other included files don't get declared!

what  i propose as a temp. solution is to have forward declarations before header import restriction, so that even in case of cycles, all forward declarations are there in a file.